# Массовая распаковка zip файлов в один каталог под ОС windows

Tags: windows, файлы, zip

Есть каталог с кучей zip файлов, необходимо содержимое этих файлов свалить в один каталог за один проход любым способом. ОС windows.

Comment: `for %f in (*.zip) do pkunzip ...` - не?

Comment: под windows нет pkunzip, нашел бесплатный архиватор 7z

Comment: У WinRar под Windows в контекстном меню есть пункт `извлечь в текущую папку`. Выделяете все zip файлы - и выбираете этот пункт.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian это правило только на rar архивы распространяется, в случае с zip распакуется только первый в очереди файл.

Comment: @perfect в версии WinRAR 4.00 у меня извлекаются все архивы (zip).

Answer (score 5):

Помог бесплатный архиватор [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (консольная версия), по подсказке

> @Pink Tux

(выражаю ему свою благодарность за помощь) созрел следующий консольный сценарий:

```
for %f in (*.zip) do 7z x %f
```

выполнять из под командной строки находясь в каталоге с zip-файлами и использовать опцию `e` вместо `x` если не надо соблюдать вложенность внутренних каталогов архивов. Если утилита 7z у вас не прописана в системной переменной `path`, то можете ее просто положить в каталог с zip-файлами.